# What was the meaning of a special character on the shebang line?

Tags: zsh

I saw a script like below,

```
#! /bin/zsh -
del=10
rm -f /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*(ND.Om[1,$del])
```

What was purpose of adding `-` on a shebang line?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A - or -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Which means that bash will not accept any of its option. Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.

An argument of - is equivalent to --. This is done to improve script security. Some user may perform setuid based script root spoofing. To avoid interpreter spoofing you need to add -- to #!/bin/bash. This is rare but possible attack.<sup>[nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/binbash-interpreter-spoofing/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure? I was told it was what I posted in my answer :D or maybe mine is a side effect :X

Comment: There is a lot of sources at the same page I got this from.  They all say the same, so I have so say that it is right, but what do I know :-)